# Is "J'ai à boire"? ambiguous?

Tags: grammaire

I recently learned that "à boire" can be used as an abbreviation for "quelque chose à boire". As in: "Je veux à boire".

This got me wondering: if I see "Je + [conjugated verb] + à boire", will "à boire" always stand for this abbreviation?

I looked at this website (https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/verbs-with-a/). It says:

> avoir à + infinitive = to be obliged to [infinitive]

**Question**

Is **"J'ai à boire"** ambiguous? That is, could it mean "I have something to drink", as well as "I am obliged to drink"?

Comment: @lkl : i rolled-back your edit that changed the thoughtco link to your website. the website that i looked at when i wrote the question was from the thoughtco website, not your website.

Comment: They are both my sites. I was the French Guide at About.com which turned into Thoughtco after I left, but they kept my content. However, they also allowed unqualified people to edit my lessons and now they are full of mistakes.

Comment: @lkl i'll undo my rollback in this case, but note that sometimes the thoughtco site really does contain information that a related website of yours doesn't. for example,  both websites does have the "avoir à + infinitive" quote that was important to this question, but the thoughtco site has a lot else about à that your linked website doesn't have. in such cases, i might rollback your editting of the link

Comment: Thank you. You are welcome to check, of course - I'm doing the same, and also making a huge effort to add extra info to my new lessons when I find that they are lacking. Typos and serious mistakes have been added to the old site and there's no one there interested in fixing them, so I strongly encourage everyone to use my new site - and please do let me know about any gaps.

Comment: @lik tbh, i'm kind of sad that thoughtco is so .. un-navigatable. i used to be able to see all articles about Grammar, but now when i look up their artcles labelled "Grammar", it only shows about seventy. i emailed thoughtco twice about this, receiving only silence. one would have thought that good, large websites for French learners would be common and active, but this isn't the case! so lucky for us learners, you're still maintaining your website, which is a big help for us!

Comment: Also please note that TC often combined several lessons into a single page; I have them separated - e.g., https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/a-preposition/ and https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/passive-infinitive/ likely contain the information you feel is missing.

Comment: Yes, well, that's one of the reasons I left - they simply don't care (and they removed over 1,000 pages). That's why I have been rebuilding for the last 8 years.

Comment: J'ai à boire au frigo ou dans la cuisine. for example, means one thing: It means: I have something to drink in the kitchen or fridge. It is an ellipsis of: J'ai [des boissons or quelchose à boire] au frigo. It's also like: J'ai à faire ce soir. I have something to do tonight. I'm busy.

Comment: @Sé1lanceLaléa No, the formula for obligation is definitely *avoir à* + infinitive. There are many examples at http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?24;s=3275494890;r=2;nat=;sol=0;

*j'ai à parler à qqn* | *je puis avoir à parler à qqn* | *je n'ai pas à entrer dans ces considérations* | *je n'ai plus qu'à revenir* ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it is ambiguous but practically, the first meaning is the only one that will be understood unless the context strongly suggest otherwise (eg. *J'ai à boire ça ?*)

To express the "to be obliged to" meaning, we would say:

> *Je dois boire.*
>
> *Il faut que je boive.*
>
> *Il me faut boire.*

Comment: the same goes for "J'ai à manger" = "I have something to eat"

Comment: Your first sentence (that technically it is ambiguous) is what I was looking for, so thanks. (The other information is appreciated as bonus facts). French is my first second-language I'm learning, and so these little things about "could *à boire* mean two different things?" seem to be really important for me to get more comfortable with the language, and less confused as I learn it! I'll accept your answer in a few days if no one gives a more insightful answer.

Comment: @silph Isn't *I have something to drink* equally ambiguous: "I own something that I can drink" vs "There is something I need to drink"?

Comment: @jlliagre "I have something to drink" cannot mean "There is something I need to drink", at least not in my variety of English; I'd be surprised if it could in some other variety of English. However, "I have to drink something" means "There is something I need to drink" (and not "I own something that I can drink", except *maybe* in some strange context, like poetry, where typical sentence patterns are can be jumbled)

Comment: J'ai à boire ou à manger au frigo. And they mean: There's something to drink in my fridge. There's something to eat in my fridge.